# What am I, can you solve it?

Tags: riddle, word

I am a figment of your imagination.

You travel on me but only forward.

I create everything and also destroy everything if exposed to me long enough.

No one or no thing has survived me and will not.

Many have tried to conquer me and failed.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> time.

I am a figment of your imagination.

> Time is intangible.

You travel on me but only forward.

> Most of us only travel forward in time.

I create everything and also destroy everything if exposed to me long enough.

No one or no thing has survived me and will not.

> Everything begins at some point in time. Increasing entropy destroys most things over time.

Many have tried to conquer me and failed.

> People have sought immortality, but no one has been known to succeed.

Comment: Nice first riddle, but perhaps try adding more indirect clues in the future :)